# How to display the path from the root to node x, using this method: pathOf(TreeNode<E> x)

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to print the path from the root to a specified node. But the issue here that I have to use the node in the parameter, as:
public ArrayList> pathOf(TreeNode x)

I've tried this:

```
public java.util.ArrayList<TreeNode<E>> pathOf(TreeNode<E> x) {
    ArrayList<TreeNode<E>> list = new ArrayList<TreeNode<E>>();
    TreeNode<E> current = root; // Start from the root

    while (current != null) {
        list.add(current); // Add the node to the list
        if (x.element.compareTo(current.element) < 0) {
            current = current.left;
        } else if (x.element.compareTo(current.element) > 0) {
            current = current.right;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return list; // Return an array of nodes
}
```

When I'm calling the method:
System.out.println("path of : " +  tree.pathOf(66));

I'm getting this message:
incompatible types: int cannot be converted to TreeNode

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

When you call `pathOf(TreeNode<E> x)` it expects a `TreeNode` variable. Simply do something like `pathOf(new TreeNode<Integer>(arg1, arg2, ...)) // Replace arg# with suitable arguments`

In other words, don't call `pathOf(66)`, call `pathOf(someTreeNodeVariable)`

Note: If you want to print custom objects, [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4) will be very helpful to you.

Comment: I've tried it, it shows:     path of : [TreePractice.TreeNode@15db9742, TreePractice.TreeNode@6d06d69c, TreePractice.TreeNode@7852e922, TreePractice.TreeNode@4e25154f]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4